# What´s the Magento Community equivalent to Magento Enterprise 1.7.1

Tags: magento-enterprise, magento-community, version

I have a client using Magento Enterprise 1.7.1 and I was wondering what's the equivalent for that in Magento Community?

Could anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Infographic: Magento History and Evolution](http://sherodesigns.com/infographic-magento-history/), *Enterprise Edition 1.7* was released after *Community Edition 1.3* and before *Community Edition 1.4*.

It looks like both editions were not that closely coupled back in the days, so there is no general way to name the counterpart.

To check which CE comes close, compare the core module versions.

Answer (score 4):

I didn't find this post in the first place - only after creating a [new one](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101174/which-ee-version-release-is-analog-to-which-ce-version/101191#101191)

Maybe someone can need it:

```
Community Edition           Enterprise Edition
Magento CE 1.9 (5/13/14)    Magento EE 1.14 (5/13/14)
Magento CE 1.8 (12/11/13)   Magento EE 1.13 (10/17/13)
Magento CE 1.7 (4/24/12)    Magento EE 1.12 (4/24/12)
Magento CE 1.6 (8/18/11)    Magento EE 1.11 (8/18/11)
Magento CE 1.5 (2/8/11)     Magento EE 1.10 (2/8/11)
Magento CE 1.4 (2/12/10)    Magento EE 1.9 (7/19/10)
                            Magento EE 1.8 (4/14/10)
                            Magento EE 1.7 (1/19/10)
Magento CE 1.3 (3/30/09)    Magento EE 1.6 (10/30/09)
```