# Which EE version (release) is analog to which CE version?

Tags: magento-enterprise, magento-community

Is there anywhere an official list which EE version is equivalent to which CE version? Thanks

Comment: If you are looking for something official, you have to search the release archvies, there is no actual list as far as I know: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Based on your help I could create some kind of table. Thats actually what I was looking for. Thanks again!

```
Community Edition           Enterprise Edition
Magento CE 1.9 (5/13/14)    Magento EE 1.14 (5/13/14)
Magento CE 1.8 (12/11/13)   Magento EE 1.13 (10/17/13)
Magento CE 1.7 (4/24/12)    Magento EE 1.12 (4/24/12)
Magento CE 1.6 (8/18/11)    Magento EE 1.11 (8/18/11)
Magento CE 1.5 (2/8/11)     Magento EE 1.10 (2/8/11)
Magento CE 1.4 (2/12/10)    Magento EE 1.9 (7/19/10)
                            Magento EE 1.8 (4/14/10)
                            Magento EE 1.7 (1/19/10)
Magento CE 1.3 (3/30/09)    Magento EE 1.6 (10/30/09)
```

Answer (score 3):

The [Infographic from Shero Designs](http://sherodesigns.com/infographic-magento-history/) should give you a good overview. You can see which versions were released when and therefore see the connection, equality of the versions.

[image]

> For example Enterprise Edition 1.7 was released after Community
>   Edition 1.3 and before Community Edition 1.4.
>
> It looks like both editions were not that closely coupled back in the
>   days (before CE 1.5 / EE 1.10), so there is no general way to name the
>   counterpart.
>
> To check which CE comes close, compare the core module versions.

Source: [Original Post](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/72955/what%C2%B4s-the-magento-community-equivalent-to-magento-enterprise-1-7-1)

Comment: The StackExchange text editor allows quoting sentences that were copied from elsewhere. This part would then ideally be accompanied by a link to the source.

Comment: Will do, sorry !

Comment: I've taken the liberty to add the image already :)

Comment: Still added the original source of my answer, I don´t want credits for it :-)

Comment: Oh, now I get it

Comment: All good, cheers!